# How to install DISM 10 on Windows 7, replacing native DISM 6.1?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm writing the command scripts (**CMD**) to create "assemblies" of Windows by running **DISM** commands (add packages, disabling features, compressing, exporting, etc.). Serving stand-alone Windows images (wim-files) can be version of DISM no lower than the image itself! The problem is that I have Windows 7 installed on my main computer, and if I need to process an image of Windows 8.1 or 10, I have to install the required OS on the test computer and collect the "assembly" on it.

On Windows 7, you can install, for example, the latest ADK for Windows 10 (1803) that contains DISM 10. But the new version of the *dism.exe* file does not replace the one supplied with Windows 7, but is located in the "Windows Kits" installation folder. In this case, a shortcut is created in the Start menu to launch the command shell with "special parameters" from where the possibilities of DISM 10 become available by "manual" entering commands. Naturally, automatic execution of DISM 10 commands from the script is not available, since the system, in case of detection of the dism command in the script, refers to the "native" DISM 6.1.

How to make it so that under Windows 7 you can serve offline images of new versions of the OS?

Comment: I don’t see why you wouldn’t be able to run scripts from the command prompt with a modified `%PATH%`. Well except if those scripts have hardcoded paths.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. Work!

Comment: At first I was glad that it turned out. And then I discovered that something is not working. The dism /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages command from the script did not work - there was an error in the logs: there is no such command.

Comment: [That’s simply not supported on Windows 7 if I read this correctly.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-app-package--appx-or-appxbundle--servicing-command-line-options#span-idlimitationsspanspan-idlimitationsspanspan-idlimitationsspanlimitations)

Comment: Yes, for Winows 7 images - is not. But, I doing this onto Windows 10 image from Windows 7, using DISM 10.

Comment: You misunderstand. The *host OS* has to support `.appx` or `.appxbundle` for this to work.

Comment: Why is that? Where is that written?After install ADK 10 on my PC with Windows 7, I added to PATH path to folder with new DISM: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM". Now I can run DISM 10 commands from CMD. Why some commands don't work?

Comment: Dunno, ask Microsoft. I tried it with Windows 7 (doesn’t support it) and Windows 8.1 (supports it) and the behavior is as described in the “Limitations” section.